# Restore Purchase - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I want to add a restore option to my app.
I have added a button that does this 2 line:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

And I have function thats supposed to check if the restore was successful:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                //code
                break;
            case .Failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                //code
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I press the button nothing happens, it doesn't activate the paymentQueue function.

Is there something wrong with code?
What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this? Probably, the document can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734890/restore-inapp-purchase-using-swift-ios

Comment: It's the same code as mine isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the only problem, but you add yourself as transaction observer after triggering restoration of completed transactions. If `restoreCompletedTransactions()` is synchronous, or if this method sets up a callback route at this point, you will miss the response. Inverting the invocations to

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

thus may fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Setting up the delegate before triggering the action is good practice anyways, though. Just wondering: how do you detect whether the callback happens - do you have a breakpoint or log statement at the beginning of the method? Also, is there anything to restore? If there is nothing to restore, `SKPaymentQueue` will not call you back.

Comment: I have a log statement and there is a purchase to restore

Comment: if there is nothing to restore the .Failed case should activate right?

Comment: I would guess no, but the reference is not very clear about this. A better idea might be to implement `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` and `paymentQueue: restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` in your observer -- I'm sure that will also help you with debugging the overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you restore your product

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            if prodID == "product ID" {
                print("action for restored")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                //code here what to restore
        }
    }
}
```